Rocky Mountain Bee-plant
When should the seeds from a Rocky Mountain Bee Plant be planted?  Can seeds be harvested from pods picked from the plant or do you have to leave the pods on the plant to dry?

I know that plant as a spider flower (Cleome sp.). We plant those in the ground in Wisconsin in early to mid-May (near to or after the last frost date).; usually, though, the seeds from the prior year just sprout on their own.

Thank you.  Unfortunately I picked the pods from the plant in Colorado and was hoping if I dried the seeds, they would be plantable in California or Oregon.

They should be - just plant in the early spring, near to or after your last frost date.
